# Error: Attempt to apply non-function in Oracle R enterprise

Tags: r, oracle, svm, rstudio

I'm currently trying to implement **support vector machine** algorithm for classification and anomaly detection using **Oracle R Enterprise (ORE)**. I've installed the ORE packages in RStudio
and as a sample, I'm trying to execute the following code given in [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/doc.112/e36761/mining.htm#CEGGGHAE):

```
library(ORE)      
m <- mtcars
m$gear <- as.factor(m$gear)
m$cyl  <- as.factor(m$cyl)
m$vs   <- as.factor(m$vs)
m$ID   <- 1:nrow(m)
MTCARS <- ore.push(m)
```

And I got the following error:

```
Error in .ore.obj() : attempt to apply non-function
```

I think it is because `ore.push()` is not recognized but When I searched in the ORE Reference Manual it is clearly defined with an example.
So, what could be its solution?

Comment: have you loaded the package using the `library` function?

Comment: Are you able to access the documentation? Try `?ore.push`

Comment: yeah, it shows the documentation page for pull/push @flodel

Comment: Isn't the package named `OREdm`? Try `library(OREdm)`.

Comment: The package named OREdm is installed and library(OREdm) is loaded @flodel

Comment: Do you have to be connected to an Oracle DB first?

Comment: No, mtcars is like iris dataset in RStudio installed in the client machine ... I've executed all the codes step by step and the last line shows an error @Spacedman

Comment: Its trying to push `m` to the Oracle database and failing. Are you connected to an Oracle database? What does traceback() tell you after the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you connected to your database using ore.connect?

```
ore.connect(user = "<userid", sid = "<sid>"
            , host = "<dbserver>"
            , password = "<userpwd"
            , all=TRUE)
```

Comment: Actually, I'd connected to the Oracle database providing all these parameters. But, It worked when I restarted my R-studio and executed the same script. Anyway, thanks for giving an answer alerting me for being connected to database.

Answer (score 0):

ore.connect - controls whether to automatically connect to ORE inside the closure. This is equivalent to doing an ore.connect call with the same credentials as the client session. The default value is FALSE.

```
ore.is.connected()                               ## TRUE

ore.doEval( function(){ ore.is.connected() } )   ## FALSE

ore.doEval( function(){ ore.is.connected() },    ## TRUE
            ore.connect=TRUE
            )
```

Therefore it follows this throws an error:

```
> ore.doEval( 
+   function()
+   { 
+     require(ORE)
+     ore.load("myData")
+   }
+ )
Error in .oci.GetQuery(conn, statement, data = data, prefetch = prefetch,  : 
ORA-20000: RQuery error
Error in OREbase:::.ore.dbGetQuery(qry) : attempt to apply non-function
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQEVALIMPL", line 104
ORA-06512: at "RQSYS.RQEVALIMPL", line 101
```

But this is fine:

```
> ore.doEval( 
+   function()
+   { 
+     require(ORE)
+     ore.load("myData")
+   },
+   ore.connect=TRUE
+ )
[1] "FOO" "BAR"
```